# REGEXP word match

Tags: mysql, regex, match

I have a script where I am attempting to match a new jobtitle to an existing one in the database.

```
SELECT 
a.title AS JobTitle,
j.Description  AS MatchedJobTitle,
f.Description      AS Family,
p.ShortDescription AS ColourComplexity,
j.IsCustomerFacing,
j.JobTitleID
FROM JobTitle j
CROSS JOIN Staging.TMP_OC1 a
INNER JOIN JobFamily f ON j.JobFamilyId = f.JobFamilyID
INNER JOIN Pathways p ON f.PathwaysID = p.PathwaysID        
WHERE a.title REGEXP CONCAT('([[:<:]]|^)', j.Description, '[s]?([[:>:]]|$)');
```

The Staging.TMP_OC1 table has one record which is the new job title, in this case Software Developer,USA.
I would like to match it to the dbs existing job title which is 'software developer'.
The regexp code above works for some job titles but not others.
Please assist in developing a more comprehensive one.

I am using mysql V8.

Comment: `works for some job titles but not others`: Please provide a dataset and some examples where it does work, and where it doesn't. This will help people to understand what the issue really is.

Comment: does not work for these : - zzzDeveloper - Junior Helpdesk Engineer (Learnership) - Forecourt attendant required in Mid - Information Technology Enablers (12 month ITE Programme) - Front End (React) Developers:

Comment: works for these : Direct Sales Assistant
Shopify Design/ Web Developer
SALES CONSULTANT
Sales and Marketing
Short-Term working opportunity Graduate Programme

Comment: `[[:<:]]` is old-style word boundary supported by Spencer library. Starting from version 8.0.4 MySQL uses ICU library which does not support it. See [Regular Expression Compatibility Considerations](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/regexp.html). So use std. `\b` instead.

Answer (score 0):

- You don't need to test for beginning/ending of string; those are "word boundaries".
- MySQL 8.0 uses `\b` for both word boundaries, instead of `[[:<:]]` and `[[:>:]]`
- In some situations, 8.0 needs the backslashes doubled up.

This may work:

```
REGEXP CONCAT('\\b', j.Description, 's?\\b')
```